# PHP Curl Randomly Hangs without errors

Tags: curl, openssl, ubuntu-14.04, freeze, php-5.5

**The question is for developer, sysadmins and people who faced with this problem.
Any help will be appreciated.**

I have *4 running php scripts*, which execute curl to get headers from websites. After awhile scripts hang (not all in the same time). I am sure for 100% that each script hangs after curl_exec() function according to my logs.

- I have curl_close()
- CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT = 120
- CURLOPT_TIMEOUT = 120
- CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE = true - explicitly close when it has finished
- CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false
- CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST = false

To tell the truth **I experimented a lot** with parameters and looks like it doesn't help at all. Moreover verbose mode with redirecting stderr into file isn't a solution, because it hangs in the middle of curl and never reach the end of execution. No logs could be applied to curl inside php.

However I did some **system check**.

```
$ sudo strace -p 8824
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {124050, 654708486}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {124050, 654743020}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {124050, 654776675}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {124050, 654810241}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {124050, 654844540}) = 0
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 0 (Timeout)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {124051, 656031748}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {124051, 656071876}) = 0
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {124051, 656144591}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {124051, 656178423}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {124051, 656213407}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {124051, 656248064}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {124051, 656282940}) = 0
```

Looks like it has retry in file descriptor fd=5

```
$ sudo ls -lh /proc/8824/fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 se se 64 Feb 19 11:39 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 se se 64 Feb 19 11:39 1 -> /var/www/html/SE/logs/tweetscan.1502191014.4431.log
l-wx------ 1 se se 64 Feb 19 11:39 2 -> /var/www/html/SE/logs/tweetscan.1502191014.4431.log
lrwx------ 1 se se 64 Feb 19 11:39 3 -> /var/lib/php5/sess_rlbj4aog6gukb725ao3nks2084
l-wx------ 1 se se 64 Feb 19 12:09 4 -> /tmp/curl_8824
lrwx------ 1 se se 64 Feb 19 12:09 5 -> socket:[688848]
```

As the problem is inside curl I

- updated php5-curl
- upgraded curl from 7.35 to 7.40
- upgraded openssl from "OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014" to "OpenSSL 1.0.2 22 Jan 2015"

Also each time making restart. None of the solution helped.

**About OS:**

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

> PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6
>
> curl 7.40.0
>
> OpenSSL 1.0.2 22 Jan 2015
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Another problem is: if script hangs, it's impossible to get its state, kill it and restart. Everything shows that it's working, the only log shows that process does nothing.

Kind regards

Comment: Hi @Oleg Matei - did you come up with a solution or work around?

Comment: the only solution I had is to have another script monitoring, killing and starting processes when it's need it. You can do it manual or automate it, but you need make sure that killed process will not break data consistency.